# Select only if empty

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a table of users and a table of things they have on a list -

to show all users who have items on a list I can join the two tables `users` and `user_lists` on `user_id`

e.g.

```
select u.emailaddr, u.name from users u
join user_lists uw where u.user_id=uw.user_id
group by u.name
```

**QUESTION:** How do I show all users who **DO NOT** have items on a list - to say it another way, I need a list of users who do not have entries in table user_lists

I tried this but it ran endlessly

```
select u.emailaddr, u.name from users u
join user_lists uw where u.user_id<>uw.user_id
group by u.name
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` predicate:

```
select u.emailaddr, u.name 
from users u
LEFT join user_lists uw ON u.user_id = uw.user_id
WHERE uw.user_id IS NULL;
```

---

**Or:** The `NOT IN` predicate:

```
select u.emailaddr, u.name 
from users u
WHERE u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                        FROM user_lists);
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks - is there a preference? is one less resource hungry than the other?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - It depends on your data, and the indexes setup in your tables, but there is a little thing to note; `JOIN` is safer than the predicate `IN` with the `NULL` values, if there is any `user_id` in the other table `user_lists` with `NULL` values, your query won't return any thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user_id FROM users u
EXCEPT
SELECT uw.user_id FROM user_lists uw
```

it will give you the ids that exist in users and don't exist in userlists.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` set operator.